# Pandas iterrows not appending data to second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes old and new. I wanted to compare the new dataframe with old dataframe and when their is name and category match i want to append the specific value from new dataframe to old dataframe, while my code is printing the results after if condition its not appending values. Here is my code

```
 for old in df_old.iterrows():
    for new in df_new.iterrows():
        if (old[1]['Name'] == new[1]['Name']) & (old[1]['Category'] == new[1]['Category']):

            print(old)

            #Code below not working
            old[1]['New Category'] = new[1]['Category']
            old[1]['New Sub Category'] = new[1]['Sub-Category']
            old[1]['New Name'] = new[1]['Name']
```

columns

```
df_old = ['Name', 'JobNo', 'Category', 'Sub Category', 'New Category', 'New Sub Category', 'New Name']

df_new = ['Name',  'JobNo', 'Category', 'Sub-Category']
```

Comment: Don't update an object while you are looping through it, it's not a good practice.

Comment: What's the alternative? I am quite a new to python and pandas. Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Iterating a dataframe is almost never the best way to do a thing; iterating two at once less so. Please provide a sample of your input and your preferred output so we can better understand your problem

Comment: I have two key values to compare so I need something like `on='name' & 'category'`. Will this work with merge?

Comment: `df_old.merge(df_new, on=['Name' ,'Category'],  how='left' )` worked like Charm